# Asp.net SignalR features does not work in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, signalr-hub

I have a base conroller class Asp.net framework 4.6 like this:

```
public abstract class SignalRBaseController<THub> : ControllerBase where THub : IHub
{
    private static readonly Func<IHubContext> ValueFactory = () => GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<THub>();

    private readonly Lazy<IHubContext> hub = new Lazy<IHubContext>(ValueFactory);

    protected IHubContext Hub => hub.Value;
}
```

And I converted the project to asp.net core. So, the following features does not found in asp.net core:

- IHub
- IHubContext
- GlobalHost

How can Iconvert my class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Hub`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr.hub?view=aspnetcore-2.2) and [`IHubContext<THub>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr.ihubcontext-1?view=aspnetcore-2.2) are still there. Instead of a static `GlobalHost`, you would use dependency injection.

I will not give you a straight translation of your abstract controller, since I believe that it is actually not that helpful: Assuming that you have a controller that just takes a single hub context (instead of other dependencies) seems to assume quite a lot. And the lazy pattern is not really needed here.

So instead, this shows an example controller implementation that uses a hub context as part of its dependencies:

```
public class ExampleController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IHubContext<MyHub> _myHubContext;

    public ExampleController(IHubContext<MyHub> myHubContext)
    {
        _myHubContext = myHubContext;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostMessage(string message)
    {
        await _myHubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("DoSomething", message);
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

I would also suggest you to look at [strongly typed hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-2.2#strongly-typed-hubs) since they make using the hub context a bit nicer.